# AssertionError after enabling LazyInitialization enhancement in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Posting this as it might help others in a similar situation.

We're upgrading a project from Hibernate 3.6.11 to 5.4.25, and some of the entities are mapped with lazy-loading properties. In Hibernate 3.6.11 this required the use of the Ant `org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask`. In Hibernate 5, this has been replaced with a quite different `EnhancementTask` (using enableLazyInitialization=true).

With this new approach, we're seeing errors

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.AbstractEntityEntry.overwriteLoadedStateCollectionValue(AbstractEntityEntry.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyProperty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1144)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.lambda$loadAttribute$0(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.EnhancementHelper.performWork(EnhancementHelper.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.loadAttribute(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.fetchAttribute(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.handleRead(LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.readObject(AbstractInterceptor.java:153)
    at com.sample.entity.OrderModel.$$_hibernate_read_orderpositions(OrderModel.java)
    at com.sample.entity.OrderModel.getOrderPositions(OrderModel.java:1537)
```

This happens in the sequence

1. Load entity OrderModel
2. Run preload pattern on the OrderModel instance, but crucially OrderModel.getOrderPositions() are **not preloaded**
3. Outside of the transaction, change the OrderModel instance
4. In a new transaction, save the OrderModel instance
5. Still within the transaction, iterate over OrderModel.getOrderPositions()

When accessing the collection, the above stacktrace occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(), which eventually runs

```
persistenceContext.addEntity(
        entity,
        ( persister.isMutable() ? Status.MANAGED : Status.READ_ONLY ),
        null, // <-- this is the 'loadedState'
        key,
        persister.getVersion( entity ),
        LockMode.NONE,
        true,
        persister,
        false
);
```

so an EntityEntry is created with a loadedState of null. Later, when the LazyAttributeLoadingInterceptor loads the collection and attempts to replace the loaded state for that property, the

```
assert loadedState != null;
```

fires.

I'm not sure whether this is a Hibernate bug, or our code just loads/manages entities in a way that Hibernate does not support. Our workaround was to add a

```
public class LazyAttributeSaveOrUpdateEventListener implements SaveOrUpdateEventListener {

    public static final LazyAttributeSaveOrUpdateEventListener INSTANCE = new LazyAttributeSaveOrUpdateEventListener();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(LazyAttributeSaveOrUpdateEventListener.class);

    private final transient Field loadedStateField;

    LazyAttributeSaveOrUpdateEventListener() {
        loadedStateField = ReflectionUtils.findField(AbstractEntityEntry.class, "loadedState");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        if (event.getEntity() instanceof PersistentAttributeInterceptable) {
            initializeLoadedState(event);
        }
    }

    private void initializeLoadedState(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
        final EntityEntry entry = getEntityEntry(event);
        final Object[] loadedState = entry.getLoadedState();
        if (loadedState == null && entry.getStatus() != Status.READ_ONLY) {
            // if accessing a lazy-loaded collection on this entity, org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyProperty()
            // will try to re-set the loaded state, resulting in an AssertionError if loadedState is null
            LOGGER.debug("Got empty loaded state for " + event.getEntity());
            EntityPersister persister = entry.getPersister();
            Object[] stubLoadedValue = ArrayHelper.filledArray(
                LazyPropertyInitializer.UNFETCHED_PROPERTY,
                Object.class,
                persister.getPropertyTypes().length);
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(loadedStateField);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(loadedStateField, entry, stubLoadedValue);
        }
    }

    private EntityEntry getEntityEntry(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(event.getEntry())
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                final PersistenceContext persistenceContext = event.getSession().getPersistenceContextInternal();
                return persistenceContext.getEntry(event.getEntity());
            });
    }

}
```

and register it as

```
eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE, LazyAttributeSaveOrUpdateEventListener.INSTANCE);
```

I was worried above adverse side-effects of create a null-initialized loaded state, but so far everything seems to be working.

Comment: Creating a stubLoadedValue`with null-values has the effect that Hibernate dirty checking doesn't recognize setting a value to null as dirty. A better initial value is LazyPropertyInitializer.UNFETCHED_PROPERTY, I've updated the answer

Comment: Might be worth trying out Hibernate 5.6 and also 6.2 to see if that is still an issue, and if it is, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.